# How can I manage and change other apps installed on my device from my own application?

Tags: android

I try to make an application to manage and change other applications installed on my mobile device. I know how to open other apps from mine. I want to find a way to read somehow others apps api and manage them on background, like Android alarm clock which the api is given by Google.

To be more specific:

I have my app and some other app which makes pizza.

```
package com.ppapadop.pizzatime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button addButton, removeButton, showButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        removeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
        showButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showButton);
    }


    public void addPizza(View v)
    {
         // Load new activity to add pizza
    }

    public void removePizza(View v)
    {
         // Load new activity to remove pizza
    }

    public void showPizza(View v)
    {
         // Load new activity to show pizza
    }
}
```

So I want to get and use these methods (addPizza, removePizza, showPizza), just like I use for alarm clock these:

```
public void runAlarmAction(String actionString) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(actionString, "-");

    Intent addAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

    addAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    addAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, st.nextToken());
    addAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    addAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    addAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);

    gContext.startActivity(addAlarm);
}
```

Comment: Another app cannot invoke the methods you cite on the pizza app, as that is not an API published by the pizza app.

Comment: Ok. So if i want to know and use these methods, pizza app's developer has to publish an API. Like alarm clock. How can i make an API for an app and publish for everyone? And how can i take these data if there is a public API for an app?

Comment: That would be 100+ pages in a book. After all, you can all third parties to start an activity, start a service, bind to a service, send a broadcast, get database-style data from a `ContentProvider`, or consume streams published by a `ContentProvider`. Any or all of those would be an API published by your app. And that is just the standard Android IPC mechanisms, let alone things like having a `ServerSocket` (e.g., embedded HTTP server in your app).

Comment: So first big problem is at API itself. It has to be too big to cover all possibilities. Am i right?

Comment: But that is not my problem. My app needs only to read this API. If there is exists. Where can i find it and how can i read it?

Comment: "Where can i find it and how can i read it?" -- you talk to the developer and ask them "hey, what APIs does your app expose?". Sometimes, the app developer may have this documented on some Web site associated with this app.

Comment: I want to do this automatically. The basic idea is that my app will search for installed apps, get somehow their APIs and create a simple UI to manage these apps.

Comment: "I want to do this automatically" -- that is not possible. There is no requirement for a third-party app to have an API that can be programmatically discoverable, let alone in some way for which you can dynamically build a UI. For example, take the `AlarmClock` example from your question. The only reason you know how to write that code is because you read documentation for it. There is no way at runtime for you to determine what `Intent` extras are available for that `Intent` action, let alone what data types those extras need to be, what would constitute valid values for them, etc.